# Efficiently convert between equivalent structs in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, casting, copy

I am communicating between two libraries which use equivalent structs. For example:

```
struct MyVector {
    public float x, y, z;
}

struct TheirVector {
    public float x, y, z;
}
```

Currently I am "casting" between these types by copying each of one's members into an instance of the other. Knowing how C# stores structs in memory, isn't there a much more efficient way of doing this with pointers?

Additionally, let's say I have two arrays of these equivalent structs:

```
MyVector[] array1; // (Length 1000)
TheirVector[] array2; // (Length 1000)
```

Isn't there a way to copy the whole block of memory from array1 into array2? Or even better, could I treat the entirety of array1 as of type array2 without creating a copy in memory?

I'm sure the answer requires pointers, but I have only used pointers in C++ and have no idea how C# implements them.

Does anyone have any examples on how to achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to use a union struct with explicit layout?

Comment: @Charlieface I'm unfamiliar with union structs. What do they do exactly?

Comment: A struct that has attribute `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` with two fields of those other structs, each having `[FieldOffset(0)]`. You need to make sure that the layout of the two inner structs match each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you're absolutely 100% sure that they have the same memory layout, you can coerce between them. The preferred way of doing this (to avoid too much `unsafe` / pointers) is: spans. For example:

```cs
var theirs = MemoryMarshal.Cast<MyVector, TheirVector>(array1);
```

This gives `theirs` as a `Span<TheirVector>`, *without* copying any of the actual data. Spans have a very similar API to arrays/vectors, so most things you expect to work: should work exactly as you expect. You simply have a typed reference to the same memory, using a different type.

Comment: Is the memory layout of structs even specified though? If it is implementation dependent then how can we ever be 100% sure that the memory layouts are the same?

Comment: @Sweeper in the example given, we can have confidence that they will be compatible; if you wanted to be *more* confident, explicit layout attributes would be nice

Comment: Ah memory layout attributes! I forgot about those!

Comment: Does this work with .NET 4.x? I've included the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace but can't find the MemoryMarshal class

Comment: @LouiEriksson you'll need `System.Memory` (available as a NuGet package): https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/ - however, note that many of the best features of spans etc don't work *as great* in .NET Framework (because of missing JIT support). Frankly, you should treat .NET Framework (4.x etc) as legacy, these days.